# How to optimized my code in Mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql

I hava three tables called `t_asset,t_device and t_asset_device`.The relationship between `t_asset` and the `t_device` is multiple pairs.Each table column is :

```
t_asset :id , asset_name,asset_code,create_time,creator
t_device:id, device_name,device_code,latitude,longitude,create_time,creator
t_assets_device:id,asset_id,device_id,create_time,creator
```

Now I want to get all the t_asset and the latitude,longitude of the first device,So I write the code and function like these:

```
fun_getLatitudeByAssetId(`assetId`  varchar(50)){
BEGIN
declare v_latituede DECIMAL(10,5) DEFAULT(-1) ; 
select  latitude  into  v_latituede  
from t_device tDevice
 inner join t_assets_device  tAssetsDevice
 on tAssetsDevice.asset_id=assetId and
  tDevice.id=tAssetsDevice.device_id
 and  tDevice.latitude!=-1
  ORDER BY tDevice.id desc
    limit 0,1; 
return v_latituede; 
END
}

fun_getLongititueByAssetId(`assetId`  varchar(50)){
BEGIN
declare v_longititue DECIMAL(10,5) DEFAULT(-1) ; 
select  longititueinto  v_longititue
from t_device tDevice
 inner join t_assets_device  tAssetsDevice
 on tAssetsDevice.asset_id=assetId and
  tDevice.id=tAssetsDevice.device_id
  and  tDevice.latitude!=-1
  ORDER BY tDevice.id desc
    limit 0,1; 
return v_longititue ; 
END
}
```

The final query sql is:

```
select tAsset.*,fun_getLatitudeByAssetId(tAsset.id) latitude,
fun_getLongititueByAssetId(tAsset.id) longititue from t_asset tAsset
```

It seems that I have query the latitude and longititue two times,If I want to get the other field from the t_device,I do not want to write another function
like fun_getDeviceCodeByAssetId, How can I optimized my code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think a function or procedure is the way to go - why not just define a view that has asset_id + all the other fields you want? Then just join to it on asset_id rather than calling functions. In addition to just being cleaner, I'd be concerned about performance with row rather than set processing with the function approach (this is total speculation, I don't have deep enough knowledge of MySQL to know how it's handled)

Comment: I don't know if the efficiency is low when using view.

Comment: Well... you could try it? A view is just a chunk of predefined SQL - it will be as efficient as the SQL is. The view will almost certainly perform better than row by row processing in a user defined function.

Answer (score 2):

Is it really necessary to do it with functions?

You can do it with views, for example:

```
create view latitudeLongitude as
select  latitude,longitude,asset_id  
from t_device tDevice
inner join t_assets_device  tAssetsDevice
on tDevice.id=tAssetsDevice.device_id
and tDevice.latitude!=-1;
```

Finally your last select should look like this:

```
select tAsset.*,latitudeLongitude.latitude,
latitudeLongitude.longititue 
from t_assettAsset inner join latitudeLongitude 
on t_assettAsset.id = latitudeLongitude.asset_id
```

Comment: I don't know if the efficiency is low when using view.

Comment: if you can go with functions if you want. you can do a function with an extra param that indicates if you want the latitude or the longitude, in this case there will be  just one function, but you will be calling it twice in your final sql, so the sql statement inside the function will execute twice anyways

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to return several values at once then you should rather declare a stored procedure, not a function. Then you'll be able to write  `select latitude, longitude from ...` inside your procedure and then call it with a command like `call getLatAndLong(...)`

Comment: It seems that procedure  can not be called in a query sql.